How can I write to the Azure App Server - Application Event logs
In Azure App Server, when there is an issue, I go to:

Diagnose and solve problems
Application event logs

It then shows a list of logging messages.
Is there a way I can write to this not using ILogger? I want to do this in two cases:

If my ILoggerProvider throws an exception I need to write that somewhere.
In Main() (I have a Blazor app) before the loggers are registered, if I hit an exception


Are you trying to figure out what exceptions are thrown in your Blazor App on Azure App Service?

@SambathChan Short answer - yes. Long answer is if my ILoggerProvider throws an exception writing a log message, I want to write that exception somewhere and then throw the exception away and continue running. An exception in the logger should have no impact on the rest of the program.

I am not aware if there is a way to log exceptions before loggers are registered. However, App Service allows you to temporarily enable logging in App Service logs and then view the exceptions in the Log stream. Another option is to enable Application Insights for your App Services, and you can check the thrown exceptions in Application Insight.

You can use System.Diagnostics.EventLog.

As per this GitHub Doc you cannot write any logs to EventLog.

@DavidThielen -  This SOThread address the same issue. In ApplicationInsights you have an option to see the Events
